# Running awk from inside CMake execute_process

Tags: awk, cmake

I am trying to run `awk` inside CMake `execute_process` and I am somehow failing to get the expected result. I *think* I must be running afoul of some escaping rules, but I am not sure what else I need to escape here. Let me demonstrate by way of an MWE.

Consider the following `version.h` (header guard left out for brevity):

```
#define LIB_MAJVER             1
#define LIB_MINVER             2
#define LIB_PATCH              3
#define LIB_BUILD              4
```

Now consider the following straightforward `awk` command:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^#define/ && $2 ~ /^LIB_(MAJVER|MINVER|PATCH|BUILD)$/ { print "set(${PRJNAME}_" $2 " " $3 ")" }' version.h
```

The output is expected to look like this (and does when executed from the shell):

```
set(${PRJNAME}_LIB_MAJVER 2)
set(${PRJNAME}_LIB_MINVER 9)
set(${PRJNAME}_LIB_PATCH 9)
set(${PRJNAME}_LIB_BUILD 1)
```

... which is what I intend to `include()` right after generating it from the version header.

Now consider the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(PRJNAME foobar)

project (${PRJNAME})
find_program(AWK awk mawk gawk)

if(AWK MATCHES ".+-NOTFOUND")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL: awk (and mawk and gawk) could not be found (${AWK}).")
else()
    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${AWK}" '$1 ~ /^#define/ && $2 ~ /^LIB_(MAJVER|MINVER|PATCH|BUILD)$/\ { print "set(${PRJNAME}_" $2 " " $3 ")" }' "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h"
        RESULT_VARIABLE AWK_EXITCODE
        OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake"
        )
    message(STATUS "Exit code from awk: ${AWK_EXITCODE}")
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake)
endif()
```

The output of `execute_process` is:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: '$1
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

... which suggests that what I am trying to execute gets passed verbatim rather than arguments being stripped of their outer quotes. So I didn't even bother to escape the occurrences of `$` in the `awk` command, which I expect have to be escaped.

Now one way to go about this would be to dump this into a shell script as a file (and during development verify that it works with the CMake versions we use). Another *should* be to use `/bin/sh -c`, but that raises the question how I can pass that one long command string ...

However, this seems cumbersome and redundant, given there should be a way to achieve what I want.

NB: I am using CMake 3.12.2 on Linux.

---

I should add that I tried to replace the `COMMAND` string by the following to test my hypothesis of being able to pull this off with `/bin/sh -c`.

```
COMMAND /bin/sh -c [[[ "${AWK}" '$1 ~ /^#define/ && $2 ~ /^LIB_(MAJVER|MINVER|PATCH|BUILD)$/\ { print "set(${PRJNAME}_" $2 " " $3 ")" }' "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h" ]]]
```

The result was this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11:
  Syntax Error in cmake code at column 180

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Unlike to double quote (`"`), single quote (`'`) has no special meaning in CMake. This is why it separates words in `'...'` argument. Inside double quoted string, double quotes can be escaped with `\"`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that helped me figure out how to do it. Thanks. Going to answer it for future visitors' benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The comment by [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) helped me figuring out what was going on (reproduced here, since the actual comment may go away):

> Unlike to double quote (`"`), single quote (`'`) has no special meaning in
>   CMake. This is why it separates words in `'...'` argument. Inside double
>   quoted string, double quotes can be escaped with `\"`.

So I rewrote the `COMMAND` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(PRJNAME foobar)

project (${PRJNAME})
find_program(AWK awk mawk gawk)

if(AWK MATCHES ".+-NOTFOUND")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL: awk (and mawk and gawk) could not be found (${AWK}).")
else()
    execute_process(
        COMMAND /bin/sh -c "\"${AWK}\" '$1 ~ /^#define/ && $2 ~ /^LIB_(MAJVER|MINVER|PATCH|BUILD)$/\ { print \"set(\${PRJNAME}_\" $2 \" \" $3 \")\" }' \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h\""
        RESULT_VARIABLE AWK_EXITCODE
        OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake"
        )
    message(STATUS "Exit code from awk: ${AWK_EXITCODE}")
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake)
endif()
```

The gist is that I am passing the whole `awk` command to `/bin/sh -c`, quoted by double quotes and any quotes embedded inside the outer double quotes needed to be escaped, just like the `$` character.

Comment: Don't you also need to escape the `$`s in the awk script to stop the shell populating `$1`, etc. with positional parameters rather than awk using them for fields? idk as I've no idea what "Cmake execute_process" is but the code you posted looks suspicious.

Comment: @EdMorton that's why that `awk` script is enclosed by single quotes, so the shell won't bother to expand these as shell variables.

Comment: If that were the whole picture though then you wouldn't have to escape the double quotes inside the awk script. Try on the command line `sh -c "echo 7 | awk '{print $0}'"` and it'll output 0 while `sh -c "echo 7 | awk '{print \$0}'"` will output 7. If it works in your "Cmake execute_process" environment that's fine though, just wanted to raise the flag.

Comment: @EdMorton you may be looking at the wrong flag ... as Tsyvarev pointed out so candidly, CMake won't treat single and double quotes differently. So what `sh` gets to see is the _command_ in the outer double quotes **with the first layer of escaping removed**. Since CMake does not care about `$1` and to `sh` the command reads (shortened) `"${AWK}" '$1 ~ ... { ... }' "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h"` `sh` has _no business whatsoever_ in expanding `$1` either before `awk` gets to see it. Basically you're falling into the same trap I fell into regarding CMake and quoting ...

Comment: I'm not looking at any flag, as I mentioned I dont know what "Cmake" is, I just saw some suspicious looking code so I thought I'd let you know about it so you could consider whether or not it is a problem. Sounds like it's not - great.

Comment: TIL: `if` in CMake will treat a variable that ends in "-NOTFOUND" as false. So you can just do `if (NOT AWK)` instead of "if (AWK MATCHES..."

Comment: +1 thanks for this. My awk command is significantly simpler, but I was able to run it without invoking another shell: `COMMAND "${AWK}" "{printf \"%s\", $NF}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GLIBC_VERSION)`. The trick was to get rid of the standard single-quotes around the print curly braces, since there is no shell that has to protect them.
I gave one quick try to get your awk command to work without calling `sh`, but it didn't work easily.